# Word for lying while bragging/boasting

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

This is a single-word/idiom/phrase/expression-request, so basically I'll take anything that fits the bill.

I'm trying to translate the Chinese word 吹牛 - which dictionaries will tell you means to brag/to boast- but it actually also refers to things that are usually all untruths and lies.

I thought, originally, that one of the translated words would work: *he's just bragging* (i.e.: it's not, actually, true) - but the definitions provided by Google/Oxford only say:

> **brag:**
>
> 1. say something in a boastful manner
> 2. a boastful statement
>
> ---
>
> [v] **boast:**
>
> 1. talk with excessive pride and self-satisfaction about one's achievements, possessions, or abilities.
> 2. (of a person, place, or thing) possess (a feature that is a source of pride).
>
> ---
>
> **synonyms**:  brag, crow, swagger, swank, gloat, show off, blow one's own trumpet, sing one's own praises, congratulate oneself, pat oneself on the back; exaggerate, overstate; preen oneself, give oneself airs; [informal] big, blow hard, lay it on thick, shoot one's mouth off; skite, big-note oneself
>
> ---
>
> [n] **boast**:
>
> 1. an act of talking with excessive pride and self-satisfaction.

There's not realy anything talking about *lies*.

So, is there an apt idiom/word/phrase (a verb) that captures the idea of bragging *and* lying at the same time?

Comment: If you are looking to emphasize the lie you could always modify boast with something like - 'deceitful boasts' , or "boasting deceit", or "boasting deceptions"  but they aren't idioms

Comment: How about "campaign" as in, "the politician campaigned in ..."? (Kidding)

Comment: Although it's not an exact match for what you want, I'm kind of fond of [bloviate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bloviate), because it *sounds* so much like what's going on: *Talk at length, especially in an inflated or empty way.*

Comment: neither bragging nor boasting imply  falsehood.

Comment: Another great word—and one that works both as a verb and as a noun—is **blather**. As a verb: "to talk foolishly at length—often used with _on_." As a noun: "voluble nonsensical or inconsequential talk or writing." Both definitions are from _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003).

Answer (score 36):

A possible idiom is "trumping [it] up". From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trump%20up):

> Definition of trump up
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1:  to concoct especially with intent to deceive :  fabricate, invent
>
> 2 *archaic*:  to cite as support for an action or claim

Comment: At first I thought this was a joke. Personification? Allusion? Or perhaps an example of anthropomorphism, but no, this is literally true and perfect!

Comment: This particular phrase carries a heavy implied meaning of a fabricated *accusation* (ie: ...the defendant denied the allegations and dismissed the *trumped-up charges* as wild exaggerations).

Comment: @J... I think we'll see it come to have a somewhat more broad connotation in the days to come.

Comment: I'm used to hearing this in a legal environment like saying someone was arrested on "trump-ed up charges"

Comment: I get the humor, but this phrase isn't commonly used today in the sense the OP describes. At least not in American English. Maybe in 3 or 4 years.

Comment: @jpmc26 "trumping it up" is weird. But "trumped up" is very natural (google for many examples)

Comment: @Mitch Yes, but it's not in the sense the OP describes. It typically means, as others have commented here, that a legal charge has been made falsely. In fact, it's typically used to imply some kind of dishonesty (at the very least, intellectual dishonesty or legal trickery) on the part of the accuser.

Comment: Oh. Right. Now I get it. Yes, 'trumped up' is not really for bragging falsely but blaming (or really charging with a crime) falsely.

Comment: It has nothing to do with legal charges, that is why it is used as a modifier and "charges" is explicit. The phrase goes back to at least the 18th century. Perhaps you mean to say "it typically is used when referring to false charges." It means "forged or false."

Comment: @Yorik Are you sure? http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/trumped-up I can't imagine Merriam-Webster's dictionary targeting English learners would explicitly call out criminal charges if it was commonly used otherwise. This matches my own experience as well; I've never heard it outside of some kind of legal context that I can recall.

Comment: @jpmc26: google books has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 26):

[Full of hot air](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/full+of+hot+air)

A person who is full of hot air is a person who talks a lot but whose words carry no substance. This does not always refer to outright lies (It can, of course.), but if not, the claim in question is so unrelated, confused, exaggerated, or misleading that the person may as well be lying. This phrase is informal, dismissive, and somewhat insulting.

The phrase has variations on "hot air":

- it
- bull
- [Expletives referring to excrement](/a/326324/16310)
- A combination of the last two: "bull [expletive]"
- beans (This can also mean that something is [lively](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_of_beans), though. So only use if the context makes it clear you wouldn't be saying that.)

Naturally, the versions containing curse words express greater discontent with the person.

Comment: Don't forget "waffle"

Comment: You can write *BS* or someone is full of *bull shit* within answers, if they answer the question. These  won't be censored.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm aware. I just prefer not to swear. Thanks.

Comment: @user3306356 Full of waffle? I don't think that's a standard idiom, although it would probably be understand as a reference to these more common phrases.

Comment: "Full of beans" also has another meaning of "lively" or "in high spirits", so it may not be the best choice.  (In fact, I had only ever heard it in this other sense until I [looked it up just now](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_of_beans).)

Comment: Wouldn't you also use 'full of hot air' for a lie that wasn't bragging?i.e.: 'He said John Elway had better statistics than Peyton Manning but he was full of hot air.'? I'm not sure that 'full of hot air' means -both- bragging and lying

Comment: @Tom22 Hm. You have a point that it can refer to things other than bragging, but it always carries a connotation of **pride** or smug superiority or believing more of oneself than warranted. The person believes either themselves or their opinions/beliefs/position to be superior. In context, if the person is talking about themselves, it would certainly be understood to refer to unsupported boasting.

Comment: yeah, someone full of hot air is almost always full of pride, whether it's about themselves or just being a know it all.  I feel that in the word.. just depends on how it needs to be used

Comment: Someone full of hot air has an _inflated_ view of himself.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I've actually had the reverse experience. I've never heard of it being used the way you describe until your comment. Could this be a country or regional difference? I'm American.

Answer (score 19):

***self-aggrandizing***

> ***[freedictionary.com self-aggrandizing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-aggrandizing)***
>
> Also found in: Thesaurus.
>   **self-ag·gran·dize·ment** (sĕlf′ə-grăn′dĭz-mənt)
>   n.
>
> The act or practice of enhancing or exaggerating one's own importance, power, or reputation.

It is the *exaggeration* and *enhancing* that make the boast untrue

Comment: There is no connotation of falsehood here as requested by the OP.

Comment: 'enhancing' or 'exaggerating' is a degree of falsehood ... perhaps not enough for the OPs desire though.  I'll put it this way... you'd call a aggrandizing person 'full of sh**' while a boastful person would just be "full of themselves" : ) .  I'd have to understand the conotations of the chinese word as used in china to know if it gave any clue of what type of lie they made.

Comment: This is particularly relevant as the director of the CIA said Donald Trump was self-aggrandising.

Answer (score 17):

**Bluster.**

Blustering has a very similar meaning to bragging, but it implies that the blusterer can't back it up. It's usually used in a context of threats, but works fine elsewhere.

You might also be looking for "vainglory," which is archaic, but has a very similar meaning to what you describe, or "boor," which is an annoying person, usually someone who makes such claims.

Finally, if you're looking for the most direct match, you're probably looking for "pathological liar," but that is a fairly unpleasant thing to call someone, and you may want to avoid it.

Answer (score 16):

Tell a *fish story*.  That a boastful fib (lie), or at the very least a great exaggeration.

> **fish story** and **fish tale**
>
> Fig. a great big lie. (Like a fisherman who exaggerates the size of the fish that got away.)
>
> - *That's just a fish story.*
> - *Don't try to fool me. He's a master at the fish tale. Maybe he should be a politician.*
>
> **fish story**
>
> An improbable, boastful tale, as in *He came up with some fish story about his winnings at the track.* This expression alludes to the tendency of fishermen to exaggerate the size of their catch. [Early 1800s]
>
> -- [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fish+story)

(See also *bluster*, *blowhard*.)

Comment: Alternatively, telling _tall tales_.

Answer (score 13):

## Blowing Smoke

or

## to Blow Smoke

Definitions from [Idioms.TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.Idioms.TheFreeDictionary.com):

> 1. To deceive others.
>      "He wanted everyone to believe he had a lot of experience, but I think he was just blowing smoke."
>      *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright ©2003.*
> 2. To say things that are not true in order to make yourself or something you are involved with seem better than it is.
>      "The team put on an unbelievable performance. I'm not just blowing smoke - they were great."
>      *Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright ©2006.*
> 3. tv. To state something in a way that conceals the truth. (see also smoke and mirrors.) 
>      "She is a master at blowing smoke. She belongs in government."
> 4. tv. To smoke marijuana. (Drugs.) 
>      "Frank sits around blowing smoke when he’s not selling."
>      *McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions Copyright ©2006*
> 5. To speak deceptively.
> 6. To brag or exaggerate.
>      *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright ©2016* ##Blowing Smoke  /  to Blow Smoke##

Comment: You probably just want to edit your changes into this answer rather than submit an entirely new answer. That way you can maintain your reputation already earned on this one.

Comment: @Mitch With a new account also...why done with a new account? lol

Comment: @Jean (and Jean) if you have created two accounts, please see the Help about [how to unite them](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 13):

If you want a single word, I can only think of the crass ***[bullshit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullshit)***. It's not a word you can say in mixed company. It's euphemism is simply "bull". As a noun and verb it very much implies complete lies, with connotations of intention to deceive.

Common phrases include:

> That's a load of bullshit!
>
> He's just giving me bullshit.
>
> Quit bullshitting me! *or* Don't bullshit me!
>
> I bullshit the whole way through that interview.
>
> I smell bullshit.

Less commonly, you might also see horseshit or just plain shit.

Synonyms might include the following, but they all lack a certain zing you get from bullshit (possibly because it's a curse). I've put the ones I believe closer in meaning at the top.

- hogwash
- bunk
- baloney
- rubbish
- crap
- flim-flam
- malarkey
- phooey
- poppycock

None of these, including bullshit, *must* connote boasting, but they certainly don't exclude it. They do all imply falsities, however, given the right context.

In a commerce context, there is ***[puffery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puffery)***. It fits boasting, but not really "entire lies", and using it outside of someone trying to sell something is out of place. If the context fits, I'd use it.

I suspect that the common phrase "You gotta be shitting me" has it's roots in bullshit, however, that phrase is more commonly used to announce amazement at recently received news.

Comment: Beat me to it. The person who is a "lying bragdart" is also called a "bullshit artist" in my country of Australia :-D  "What a load of bull dust" is also used as a euphemism for a load of baloney.

Comment: If they want a verb that is useful in polite company, "hogwashing" sounds the best to me from the list.

Comment: Please note that the NeoAmerican Church made a very clear distinction between BullShit and HorseShit, Horseshit perhaps being more nearly what's in question here. I lost track of my copy of the catchism sometime before Woodstock, and can't (for some reason...) recall the details at the moment.

Comment: Another idea for the list of common variants: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%20are%20full%20of%20shit

Answer (score 7):

You could describe the character as a **braggart** (obviously a noun derived from the verb "brag.") https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/braggart

You could describe the behaviour as **braggadocio** - which looks like an Italian word, but is actually derived from the name of a character in a 16th-century English poem. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/braggadocio

A person who fantasizes about a life much more exciting and glamorous than their own could be described as **like Walter Mitty** or **Mittyish**. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/walter_mitty https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mittyish

Comment: The story was entitled "The Secret Life of Walter Mitty" so while there was a lot of untruth to the stories Mitty told, he only told them to himself which I think is different than what is wanted here.

Comment: +1 *Braggadocio* can actually be used to described the person and the thing being done, in fact.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like they [**"talk the talk but don't walk the walk"**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/talk-the-talk-walk-the-walk):

> If you say that someone talks the talk but does not walk the walk, you mean that they do not act in a way that agrees with the things they say.
>
> When it comes to recycling he talks the talk but he doesn't walk the walk.

Comment: This implies hypocrisy, not boasting.

Answer (score 3):

I think the phrase **false pretence(s)** fits the bill, unless I'm mistaken.

From Google:

> ***Pretence: a claim to have a particular skill or quality.***

Comment: pretence is faking so false pretence would be like saying "false faking": meaning telling the truth. -1

Comment: If you do something under false pretenses, you do it when people do not know the truth about you and your intentions→HarperCollins Advanced English Dictionary

Comment: @P.O. "False pretences" is a standard English expression, even though it does seem tautological. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/false_pretences. It refers particularly to deceiving other people with criminal intent (to commit fraud. etc). The word "pretence" on its own doesn't necessarily imply any "bad" motive.

Answer (score 1):

If the lies take the form of stories about himself then you'd say he *spins yarns*, or if he just says he can do stuff that he can't do you'd call him a *blowhard* or perhaps even a *windbag*. If he's bragging about morality you'd call him *holier-than-thou.*

If it's more bragging about his (false) achievements or so you'd call that *bluster*.

You could probably get a good distance describing the man as a *conman* or *con artist* as long as you use it as an insult. Confidence tricks take lots of subtle forms and probably someone who literally brags about himself would not be a good confidence trickster, but if it's just an insult it probably communicates something similar.

In slang you might say "he talks a big game" as shorthand for "he talks a big game but he ain't all that." If he poses as tougher than he is by making threats that he'll never follow through on, you'd say "his bark is worse than his bite."

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say that the speaker is "telling a tall tale".

Now, since 吹牛 literally means "to blow (up a) cow(skin raft)", some good alternatives might be:

- blowing smoke
- full of hot air
- bullsh*tting

Since these preserve some imagery from the original Chinese.

Answer (score -1):

Pretentious: 
*adjective*

Attempting to impress by affecting greater importance or merit than is actually possessed.