# Word for someone who is proud of something without merit?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective for someone who is proud of something that is really unimpressive or otherwise doesn't warrant pride? Some examples would be being a diehard fan of a terrible sports team or claiming that an average or indistinguishable town/city/country is 'the best'.

This is similar to blind worship, but without the religious connotation/idolization element. Something between a blind worshipper and a home-teamer.

Comment: Very closely related: [... bragging boasting but all made up of lies](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369635/request-bragging-boasting-but-all-made-up-of-lies).

Comment: I like this question. Can you give us a sample sentence with a blank where your word should go?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite a bit of that about at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Leon.

How about “blind faith”? [Here](https://thesaurus.plus/synonyms/blind_faith) are many synonyms of it which would also work...
[image]

Comment: I also found: “naively enthusiastic”, indulgent, “soft on”, gullible, beguiled, charmed, hypnotized, mesmerized, spellbound, lured, bedazzled...